# jQuery Event Subscriber - how to get event params

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile and am launching a dialog like so:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#someDiv', { role: 'dialog', params: callbackFunction });
```

I'm listening for the event, and I'd like to be able to gain access to the params defined above, but can't figure out how to access it from the following:

```
$('#someDiv').on('pageshow', function(evt){
  //hmm... how to access the role or params values above?
});
```

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can just simply use `data` to store params like:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#someDiv', { role: 'dialog'});
$('#someDiv').data('params', callbackFunction);
```

and

```
$('#someDiv').on('pageshow', function(evt){
  var someVar = $(this).data('params');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but unfortunately if I use your code, someVar === undefined.  However, if I look at $(this).data('role') it DOES show 'dialog'.

Comment: alright then use `$.mobile.changePage('#someDiv', { role: 'dialog', params: callbackFunction });` and fetch the `params` from `data method`

Comment: It's undefined whether I pass params inside the changePage call or outside as you originally indicated.  It seems that custom properties inside that object literal can't be used.